# Is there an idiom for, " Making decision all by yourself without involving or consulting others and expect them to accept it"?

Tags: idioms

I know there are some idioms meaning that you do a job alone or sth. But what I'm looking for is the one in which a person is supposed to consult with others before making final decision but he just does it all by himself and think that the others will accept the decision and all is done!

For example: When she realized that he had made all the decisions before asking for her opinion she lost her temper and said, "Hey, you just [THE IDIOM]? Don't you think we should all have a say in this?"

Comment: It's my way, or the highway

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence with a blank for where this word should go?

Comment: For example:... When she realized that he had made all the decisions before asking for her opinion she lost her temper and said, " Alright, You just [ THE IDIOM]? Don't you think we should all have a say in this? huh?"

Comment: You just *steamrolled* us.  *railroaded* us,  *did an end-run around us*   They each have slightly different connotations.

Comment: I'd go with "you just bypassed us"

Answer (score 5):

He made the decision *unilaterally*.

He made the decision *by fiat*.

Comment: Decree -"An official order that has the force of law" would be similar to the above.

Comment: Dude, you know the way things get flagged here...

Answer (score 2):

**Taking Liberty** is a good choice if you are implying about doing something without asking.

*I took the liberty and checked the editorial manager of Renie*

Comment: I thought you took the liberty *of doing something*, as in `You took the liberty of checking with the editorial manager`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word [*arrogate*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/arrogate) here:

> **arrogate** *tr. v.*
>   1. To take or claim for oneself without right; appropriate: "*That's how my cousin came to don the hand-tailored suits and to arrogate to himself the glamorous responsibility for ushering to their tables big-name customers"*
>   <sub>TFD Online</sub>

In your case, the person *arrogated to himself* the decision-making process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an idiom that does all three of these things:

- a decision
- that disregards others' feedback
- with the expectation that they accept it

I have a few idioms that do parts of what you ask. Consider this a partial answer.

1. Make a decision all by yourself without involving or consulting others: he **[put the cart before the horse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_the_cart_before_the_horse)** (suggesting he mixed up his priorities) or **[got ahead of himself](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_ahead_of_oneself)** (suggesting he took a premature action or insufficient information). Neither works by itself for your intention - there's nothing in either one that requires *others' feedback* to right the cart or make the action mature.
2. For disregarding feedback, there's little better than a **[tin ear](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tin_ear)**. It is often applied to people who can't appreciate the subtleties of music, but "tin ear" is also applied to people who disregard another's attitude or mood. Other idioms might include **turn a blind eye** or **[shut his eyes to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-a-blind-eye)**, which both involve ignoring or refusing information that may be inconvenient. The disadvantage of all of these is that none of them need pertain to decisionmaking, nor do they restrict the attitude of the people being ignored.
3. If he assumes that you will accept it, he is **taking** your consent **[for granted](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+for+granted)**. In other words, he expects your acceptance. This requires incorporating *acceptance or consent* as the object of the phrase, and of course it doesn't entail anything else you want it to mean by itself.

This is a partial answer because all three of these idioms together might work, but it'd be pretty weird and idiosyncratic, and perhaps better idioms exist. Here's an example of what combining them looks like:

> With this latest decision, Jonathan got ahead of himself, turned a blind eye to his coworkers, and took their acceptance for granted.

On second thought, it felt like I needed to specify "decision." If I do that *instead of using the first set of idioms*, maybe this would also work:

> With this latest decision, Jonathan turned a blind eye to his coworkers and took their acceptance for granted.

Answer (score 0):

"Decide unilaterally" is a nice, precise formulation proposed by @TRomano, and that's what I would say most of the time.  But you asked for an idiom, so here's a colorful one.  This is the response the shocked colleague would make, upon realizing that the arrogant person made an important decision without consulting him:

> And what am I, chopped liver?

This means, I'm so unimportant that you wouldn't bother consulting me?